# How to share files between Grunt targets?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

My Gruntfile has repeated `"files"` all over it shared between the two targets, `dist` and `dev`, of the same tasks. Here is a sample including only the Stylus problem:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

    grunt.initConfig({
        stylus: {
            dist: {
                files: { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] },
                options: { compress: true, linenos: false }
            },
            dev: {
                files: { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] },
                options: { compress: false, linenos: true }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus:dev"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["stylus:prod"]);
};
```

Is there a way to move the files config up a level so I don't have to repeat it in both targets?

Comment: why can't you say "var myFiles = { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] };" before grunt.initConfig, and then say "files:myFiles" wherever you need to?  it's just an object, no?  I'm sure you could write a function that injects a files attribute into every object too, but... I mean DRY, but at some point you're trading a lot of complexity for a little convenience.

Comment: It's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927368

Comment: The issue on the tracker: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1029

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Domenic, you can either use a POJS variable:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

    var stylusFiles = { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] };

    grunt.initConfig({
        stylus: {
            dist: {
                files: stylusFiles,
                options: { compress: true, linenos: false }
            },
            dev: {
                files: stylusFiles,
                options: { compress: false, linenos: true }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus:dev"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["stylus:prod"]);
};
```

Or you can use templates per the [Grunt "Configuring Tasks" Guide](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates).

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

    grunt.initConfig({
        stylus: {
            dist: {
                files: { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] },
                options: { compress: true, linenos: false }
            },
            dev: {
                files: "<%= stylus.dist.files %>",
                options: { compress: false, linenos: true }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus:dev"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["stylus:prod"]);
};
```

Comment: I know this is a duplicate answer, but I wanted to point out that both "template" and POJS variable approaches are equally valid.

Comment: This is the only one with POJS variable that I can see, and that does seem simplest, so accepting. Still, it's weird that you can hoist `options` but not `files`.

Comment: POJS = Plain Old JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

Check out templates: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

  grunt.initConfig({
    stylus: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"],
        },
        options: { compress: true, linenos: false }
      },
      dev: {
        files: "<%= stylus.dist.files %>",
        options: { compress: false, linenos: true }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus:dev"]);
  grunt.registerTask("prod", ["stylus:prod"]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass config into grunt, I havn't tested the below code but it should work I think. I just havn't used the config for keys before, only values. Hopefully it's a start at least.

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

  var buildConfig = {
    output: "www/bundle.css",
    files: ["stylus/*.styl"],
  };

  grunt.initConfig({
    config: buildConfig,
    stylus: {
        dist: {
            files: {<%= config.output%>: <%= config.files %>},
            options: { compress: true, linenos: false }
        },
        dev: {
            files: {<%= config.output%>: <%= config.files %>},
            options: { compress: false, linenos: true }
        }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus:dev"]);
  grunt.registerTask("prod", ["stylus:prod"]);
};
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I have approached this a couple of different ways in the past. One would be to take advantage of environment variables and use an environment variable to switch simple flags like the stylus one. Extending this approach, you can even register a task which sets a flag for you. E.g.

```
"use strict";

var env = 'DEV';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

    grunt.initConfig({
        stylus: {
            dist: {
                files: { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] },
                options: { compress: env === 'PROD', linenos: env === 'DEV' }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('production', function () {
        env = 'PROD';
    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["production", "dev"]);
};
```

You can also go the templates route or extending a base object, but I usually find flags are simple enough to work with.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using environment variables for this? Such as `process.env.NODE_ENV` to determine if it is in `DEV` or `PROD` evironment.

Comment: @Spoike You can, and it is what the first sentence said. However, that can lead to additional effort of change environment variables each task or putting the commands into a make file or `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it as a line item in your grunt config:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

    grunt.initConfig({
        cssFiles: ["stylus/*.styl"],
        stylus: {
            dist: {
                files: { "www/bundle.css": '<%= cssFiles %>' },
                options: { compress: true, linenos: false }
            },
            dev: {
                files: { "www/bundle.css": '<%= cssFiles %>' },
                options: { compress: false, linenos: true }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["stylus:dev"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["stylus:prod"]);
};
```

Have a look at the file i'm using in one of my projects if you need more examples:
https://github.com/sugendran/cheatsheet.js/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure something like this works...

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-stylus");

    var files = { "www/bundle.css": ["stylus/*.styl"] };
    var options;

    grunt.registerTask("config", function() {
        grunt.initConfig({
            stylus: {
                main: {
                    files: files,
                    options: options
                }
            }
        });
    });

    grunt.registerTask("setup-prod", function () {
        options = { compress: false, linenos: true };
    });

    grunt.registerTask("setup-dev", function () {
        options: { compress: true, linenos: false };
    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["setup-dev", "config", "stylus"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["setup-prod", "config", "stylus"]);
};
```

it looks like you can also change your config without re-calling initConfig() by directly editing grunt.config.data.